# How can I set the environment based on route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to have a different environment if I'm browsing a specific path (`domain.com/path1`), is this possible in Laravel 4 and if so, how? I know of the `$app->detectEnvironment()` method but I don't know how to use it for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the `$app->detectEnvironment()` method (in `/bootstrap/start.php`), but instead of sending on an array you use a closure.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    // get current http_host
    $baseurl = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : null;

    // our available environment
    $envs = [
        'foo' => ['foo.com', 'bar.foo.com'],
        'kex' => ['kex.foo.com']
    ];

    // default environment, you should not change this
    $environment = 'production';

    // search trough each available environment to see if it matched our http_host
    foreach($envs as $key => $env) {
        foreach ($env as $url) {
            if ($url == $baseurl) {
                $environment = $key;

                // match found, lets break our loop
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // we create segments of /our/path so we can check if it matches your condition
    $segments = explode('/', isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : null);

    // check if the first (second) segment matches our /path
    if (isset($segments[1]) && $segments[1] == 'path')
        return $environment . '-route'; // append -route to our environment and return it

    return $environment;
});
```

Line 2 to 24 mimics Laravel's default method (using arrays). What you're after below that.